# Visual Studio Cordova error 'No matching provisioning profiles found: No provisioning profiles matching the bundle identifier were found.'

Tags: ios, xcode, cordova, visual-studio-cordova

I am trying yo run my app on ios cordova app in Distribution mode using visual studio.

Build fails with following error.

```
 No matching provisioning profiles found: No provisioning profiles matching the bundle identifier ΓÇxxxx.yyy.appΓÇ¥ were found.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is telling you that you have not setup a valid distribution certificate for your app on your Mac.  iOS, Android, and Windows all require you to generate a certificate before you can sign and package your app for distribution to the appropriate app store.

See...

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/IDEs/Conceptual/AppDistributionGuide/MaintainingCertificates/MaintainingCertificates.html

...and...

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn757048.aspx#iOS

By default, Visual Studio will auto-match the distribution certificate.  If you need to override to use a different signing identity, you can place a custom build-debug.xcconfig or build-release.xcconfig file in res/native/ios/cordova.

Samples:

https://github.com/apache/cordova-ios/blob/master/bin/templates/scripts/cordova/build-release.xcconfig

https://github.com/apache/cordova-ios/blob/master/bin/templates/scripts/cordova/build-debug.xcconfig

Docs on iOS Build settings:
https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/DeveloperTools/Reference/XcodeBuildSettingRef/0-Introduction/introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40003931-CH1-SW1

Answer (score 1):

I came accross the same issue, but with me it was a stupid error on my side.

My App Id in the config.xml was different from the Id in my provisioning profile due to case sensitivity.

e.g. Id in config.xml was `com.company.MyAppName` but the bundle id in the provisioning profile was `com.company.myappname`.

So changing the config id to all lowercase helped me. Hope this helps someone else too. :)

Comment: This was exactly my problems info.plist needed to be updated (make sure your build configuration is actually using this file)